# Selecting different rows from database each calendar day

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a MySQL database with 112 rows (with ID column from 1 to 112), I need to SELECT 6 random rows (doesn't matter if sequential) to show in PHP/HTML page and to be changed daily.
The only option I think is to depend on the current date.
Is there any solution ?!

Thank you ...

EDIT:
Question was solved. Although no one really understood what I want but I keep getting down votes.

The question was : 6 Random rows EVERY DAY not every page refresh or every call from DB.

But thanks for the amazing effort. Question solved.

Comment: Use order by rand() limit 0,6;

Comment: I see you didn't put much effort into this.

Answer (score 2):

The MySQL statement `ORDER BY RAND()` will order the matching rows randomly. Combined with `LIMIT 6` you'll get six random rows.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand for reference.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `ORDER BY RAND()` to randomize the row order, then show the first 6:

```
SELECT * FROM Yourtable ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,6;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following query

```
SELECT column FROM table
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 6
```